# BITGO - Can't Get Hash on Request

Tags: python, django

What is the key to call from BitGo API to get from a webhook immediately an address receive BTC.

From my ngrok, I saw this

```
{
    "hash": "26ba9cc3218962417f529803d82dd63850b895fbee74517dff",
    "type": "transaction",
    "coin": "bitcoin",
    "walletId": "2Mzb4KMAp"
}
```

So when I did the following in the 'hook callback url', I'm getting error. 500 Error.

```
1. txId  =  request.POST.get('hash')
2. txId = request.GET['hash']
3. txId = request.POST['hash']
```

How do I get the hash since all the above method failed. I'm using Python/Django.

Comment: Can you provide any extra details about the error you're seeing? "500 Error" could be a LOT of things in your code.



It looks like BitGo POSTs to you with JSON.  If you're unable to read from the dictionary, you may need to use `json.loads(request.body)` to get a dict you can access.

Comment: Thanks @Alex it works. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Done! Super glad to hear that it helped. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BitGo API will uses POST to send JSON data to your endpoints: https://bitgo.github.io/bitgo-docs/#webhook-notifications

You'll likely need to convert the body of their POST request from JSON into a Python dict you can access more easily. You can do this with [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
bitgo_data = json.loads(request.body)
hash = bitgo_data['hash']
```